# file uploads only to a temp folder

Tags: zend-framework

I can't quite understand how file upload works. I followed this manual

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html

And this is the code I have written

form

```
$this->add(array(
            'name' => 'ipr',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type'  => 'file',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'ИПР',
            ),
        ));
```

and controller:

```
     $recomissionform = new AddrecomissionForm();
        //  $form->get('submit')->setValue('Сохранить');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $recomission = new Recomission();
            $recomissionform->setInputFilter($recomission->getInputFilter());
            // file 
            $post = array_merge_recursive(
                $request->getPost()->toArray('ipr'),
                $request->getFiles()->toArray()
            );

            echo var_dump($post);
            // file end


            $recomissionform->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($recomissionform->isValid()) {
$data=$recomissionform->getData();
                $recomission->exchangeArray($recomissionform->getData());

                //validator can be more than one...




                }

                //echo var_dump($admin);
                $this->getRecomissionTable()->Savecomission($recomission,$id);
                // Redirect to list of albums
                //  return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin');

        }

        return array('recomissionform' => $recomissionform,'noid'=>false,'id'=>$id);
    }


    //  return array();
}
```

And this is what var_dummp of $post variable

array(7) { ["place"]=> string(5) "testr" ["passDate"]=> string(10) "2013-02-22" ["nextPass"]=> string(0) "" ["disgartreason"]=> string(0) "" ["forever"]=> string(1) "1" ["submit"]=> string(18) "Сохранить" ["ipr"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(9) "htmls.PNG" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\php7C79.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(13956) } }

And questions are 1. How to set destination folder? and 2. How to populate $post only with file info not with other text fields? such as place, Passdate ets.

Comment: Consider using  Zend_File_Transfer http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.filters.html

Comment: Still doesn't work. Can't even get file name

Comment: If you want more help you will need to elaborate more on your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to just upload a file, try the below code.

Create a `FormClass` extending `Zend_Form`

```
class ABCForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init() {

            $file = new Zend_Form_Element_File('file');
            $file->setLabel('File')
                ->setDestination('/SOMEPATH/upload/')
                ->addValidator('Extension', false, 'ALLOWED MIME TYPES')
                ->setRequired(true);

            $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('ok');
            $submit->setLabel('Upload')
                ->setDecorators(array(
                    'ViewHelper',
                    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span'))
                ));
            $this->addElement($submit);


        $this->addElements(array($file, $submit));
   }
}
```

`Controller` extending `Zend_Controller_Action`

```
class ABCController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    $db = new SOMEDBCLASS();
    $form = new ABCForm();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
      $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

      if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
        if ($form->file->isUploaded()) {
          $uploadedData = $form->getValues();
          $fullFilePath = $form->file->getFileName();
          $result = $db->UPLOAD($fullFilePath);
}


HTML

<div>
  <?=$this->form->getElement('file') ?>
</div>

<div>
  <?=$this->form->getElement('ok') ?>
</div>
```

This will upload the file to the destination path.